# Column grouping in R with different mixed Values and column name in data

Tags: r

### List item

I have data which needs to grouped like below i am struggling to group the following data.

```
V1   | V2  | V3   | V4  |V5   | V6
----------------------------------
P    | PNR |Model | abd |SUB  | 2
----------------------------------
Model| abc | SUB  |  1  |Place| C
----------------------------------
Model| abc |SUB   |  1  |Place| C
----------------------------------
P    | PNR |Model | abc |SUB  | 1
----------------------------------
```

The above data should be grouped like the following below:

```
P   |Model  |SUB|Place
-----------------------
PNR |abd    |2  |
-----------------------
    |abc    |1  |C
-----------------------
    |abc    |1  |C
-----------------------
PNR |abc    |1  |
-----------------------
```

can anyone help me with the above or: the Following was strsplit_fixed for the association rule. Is there any way to get the above data as expected.
Would be really helpful

Comment: You may need to clarify the rules of how to create the desired output based on your first data frame.

Comment: Three columns which are in v1,V3 ,v5 and their corresponding values in the next columns v2,v4,V6
I need to make a single column values from 1,3,5 and lookup the values from 2,4,6 to a single column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a more efficient way, but here is an option by using a for loop to fill in the values based on the match index.

```
# Data Preparation
dt <- data.frame(V1 = c("P", "Model", "Model", "P"),
                 V2 = c("PNR", "abc", "abc", "PNR"),
                 V3 = c("Model", "SUB", "SUB", "Model"),
                 V4 = c("abd", "1", "1", "abc"),
                 V5 = c("SUB", "Place", "Place", "SUB"),
                 V6 = c("2", "C", "C", "1"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Get the column names
cols <- unique(c(dt$V1, dt$V3, dt$V5))

# Get the match indices in V1, V3, V5
m_index <- t(apply(dt[, c("V1", "V3", "V5")], 1, function(x) which(cols %in% x)))

# Create an empty matrix
m_fill <- matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

# Subsett the original data frame to only keep V2, V4, V6
dt2 <- dt[, c("V2", "V4", "V6")]

# Fill the empty matrix based on the indices in m_index
for (i in 1:nrow(dt2)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(dt2)){
    m_fill[i, m_index[i, j]] <- dt2[i, j]
  }
}

# Convert m_fill to a data frame
dt3 <- as.data.frame(m_fill)
colnames(dt3) <- cols

dt3
     P Model SUB Place
1  PNR   abd   2  <NA>
2 <NA>   abc   1     C
3 <NA>   abc   1     C
4  PNR   abc   1  <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your help precisely what i was looking for :). Will update if i have any further questions.